# redirecionamento para dentro de site

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema, com login e senha, que manda notificação, por email, para usuários, quando determinado situação ocorre.
Quando o usuário clicar no link da notificação do email, ele é redirecionado para uma página interna do sistema, PORÉM, se o usuário não estiver logado no sistema, ele será barrado.
A questão é, como fazer "login automático" desse usuário no momento do redirecionamento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## NUNCA

Nunca fazer login automático com base em links que são recebidos por email.

Existe um infinito número de cenários que podem fazer o email chegar a outra pessoa e/ou o email ser lido por terceiros.

Isso representa um risco de segurança elevado pois estás a dar acesso sem validação de credenciais! Se o email não estiver nas mãos do seu verdadeiro titular, podem aceder à área supostamente protegida sem nada mais que um clique numa hiperligação... imagina o mar de problemas que dai advêm!

Sugiro que repenses a estratégia de forma a garantires que a hiperligação funciona mas o utilizador tem sempre no mínimo que introduzir a sua password de acesso.

## Recomendação

Sugiro que o login seja sempre realizado por meio de input do utilizador, onde após validação com sucesso podes direcionar o mesmo para a página da hiperligação no email:

- No email vem a hiperligação:

  > http://www.example.com/pagina/xtpo/
- Ao chegar à página sem login realizado:

  ```
  // apanhar URL atual
  $urlAtual = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

  // guardar na sessão
  $_SESSION["minhaSessao"]["redirect"] = $urlAtual;

  // login e tal...

  // login correu bem, direcionar:
  header('Location: '.$_SESSION["minhaSessao"]["redirect"]);
  ```

**Nota:**
O sucesso desta operação e/ou a metodologia varia consoante a forma como o login é realizado e a forma como a sessão é manipulada.

Comment: Certo @Zuul, entendi.
Então esses emails que recebemos de notificações de um sistema onde temos cadastro, como por exemplo, Mercado Livre, que te avisa quando alguém comprou um produto seu e te dá um link para ver a compra, não é correto? Ou essas empresas tem, usam alguma maneira, segura, de fazer esse redirecionamento?
Valeu.

Comment: @GustavoSevero Esses emails, vão hiperligar para o web-site, mas se o login não estiver ativo, o "normal" é apresentar a página de login para que o utilizador se autentique e depois é que é direcionado para a página correta. Se já tem login ativo, o web-site sabe disso e manda o utilizador diretamente para a página correta. Ultrapassar o login por questões de conveniência para o utilizador é deitar fora toda a segurança da aplicação.

Comment: Desculpe @Zuul, era isso!!!!
Pois é, como pode-se fazer esse redirecionamento, após o usuário se logar?

Comment: @GustavoSevero Editei com um exemplo ilustrativo de como atingir o _redirect_.

Comment: Entendi @Zuul, vou tentar.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o código de como devo fazer, para você ver se está certo @Zuul.

Comment: @GustavoSevero Não deves editar a pergunta, as respostas existentes perdem o seu sentido e deixam de ser úteis ao tópico. Deves criar uma pergunta nova sobre o novo problema em mãos para que possas obter ajuda nesse novo assunto sem prejudicar este tópico.

Comment: me consegue seu email?

Comment: Pessoal, to "trancado" em como pegar a url vinda do email, e passar para a $_SESSION. Socorro @Zuul

Comment: @GustavoSevero Fazes como tenho no exemplo da resposta. Se não está claro ou não soluciona o teu novo problema, o melhor é colocares uma pergunta nova para se lidar com ele e receberes ajuda da comunidade. Aqui nos comentários é difícil resolver...

Answer (score 3):

Você pode adicionar uma coluna chamada `token` na tabela de usuários e toda vez que precisar enviar uma notificação, gere uma token nova e envie o link para uma rota de ativação aonde você possa ler o token enviado.

Você pode gerar o token da seguinte maneira:

```
$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
```

A rota seria algo do tipo:

```
www.seusite.com.br/ativa-notificacao/a127be805346054046f75a31f8e4043d
```

Nesta página você deve verificar se existe algum usuário no seu sistema com esse `token`, caso sim, você pega as informações desse usuário e salva o que for preciso na sessão, como se ele tivesse feito o login.

Quando o `token` for validado e usuário logado no seu sistema, exclua o token do usuário e só gere outro quando for necessário enviar outra notificação. É muito importante esse processo, caso contrário alguém pode ter acesso ao token de outro usuário e fazer login no nome dele.

Te indico essa solução pois uso isso para validar e-mails quando alguém cria uma conta em meu sistema, envio um e-mail de ativação.

Comment: o meu sistema não é um sistema de notificações, é um sistema para procura de pets.
Envio de notificações é só uma "tarefa" que o sistema possui para avisar outros usuários.
No caso, o que vc está sugerindo é, ao invés de fazer o login, como eu falei, o sistema permite o usuário acessar o sistema, existindo ou não esse token?
Mas isso não pode gerar problema no sistema? Pois ele barra o acesso se o usuário não fizer o login.

Comment: @GustavoSevero, não estou sugerindo uma substituição, estou sugerindo uma maneira, adicional, de logar os seus usuários através do link, desse modo o próprio link irá ativar a sessão do usuário.

Answer (score 2):

Autenticar um usuário diretamente a partir de um e-mail, embora seja um recurso bem interessante do ponto de vista de experiência do usuário, precisa ser implementado com cuidado e equilíbrio do ponto de vista da segurança do sistema.

Vou apresentar algumas abordagens, as quais incluem algumas coisas que as demais respostas já falaram.

## Preocupação com Segurança

Como o @Zuul mencionou, autenticação por link em e-mail é um grande problema de segurança. Isso incluir duas razões principais:

1. Autenticação baseada em links são fáceis de interceptar. As URLs que vc acessa ficam armazenadas em logs e podem ser rastreadas de várias formas. Existem várias formas de uma pessoa ter acesso ao link e se fazer passar por você. Por outro lado, autenticação com usuário e senha em formulários, quando utilizados em uma conexão segura, não ficam armazenados e não podem ser visualizados por um terceiro que esteja monitorando o tráfego entre cliente e servidor.
2. E-mails podem ser respondidos e encaminhados, exibindo por engano o link restrito para terceiros.

Mesmo assim, podemos pensar em diferentes formas de melhorar a experiência do usuário com links diretos sem comprometer tanto a segurança.

## Login com redirecionamento

A forma mais segura e que não afeta tanto a experiência para o usuário é fazer com que o link do e-mail aponte para uma página que execute o seguinte procedimento:

1. Verifique se o usuário está logado. Se o usuário estiver autenticado vai ter um cookie ou algo que identifique-o, certo?

   2.1. Se houver autenticação, basta redirecionar a requisição para o link do e-mail.

   2.2 Se o usuário não estiver autenticado, o sistema mostra a página de login. Após o login do usuário, o sistema deve então redirecioná-lo para o link do e-mail.

Nesta abordagem, o link original pode ser armazenado na própria URL. Exemplos:

- Endereço do e-mail:

  `http://servidor/administracao/secao1`
- Endereço da tela de login:

  `http://servidor/login?page=administracao/secao1`

Dessa forma após o login é possível saber para qual tela o usuário deve ser redirecionado.

A abordagem com autenticação faz com que seja necessário o usuário se autenticar. Porém, o login pode ser mantido por mais tempo do que a sessão atual do navegador. Por exemplo, o Evernote tem uma opção no login para "lembrar o usuário por uma semana". Isso significa que o usuário não precisaria se autenticar durante uma semana. Note que isso é viável somente para computadores privados.

## Login com *token* único

Esta é a abordagem mencionada pelo usuário @gerep. A ideia é gerar um token único por link de forma que ninguém possa adivinhá-lo e então invalidar o token após seu uso.

O problema dessa abordagem é que o usuário certamente vai tentar repetir a mesma ação algum tempo depois e terá o acesso negado. Isto é bom do ponto de vista de segurança, mas uma péssima experiência para o usuário.

## Login limitado com *token*

Outra alternativa que alguns sites como LinkedIn usam é gerar um token que não é invalidado, porém, ele dá um acesso apenas restrito ao sistema.

No caso em questão, o token pode dar acesso somente à tela referente ao e-mail. Ou talvez a telas que são apenas de visualização de dados.

Caso o usuário tente acessar alguma ação ou edição no sistema, então o login *completo* seria requisitado.

## Considerações

Enfim, defina qual o nível de segurança e, dependendo do sistema, você pode usar um conjunto de abordagens mista.